# Can the same html form input be made to appear in two different places?

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-modal

I would like to have a single form input appear in two different places.  The two inputs are essentially one and the same, so I would like them to act as one.  One of them appears in a step-by-step quiz, while the other appears at the end of a Bootstrap quiz modal.  But they both feed into the same form submission.

At the moment, I have two different controls for each input - one for the quiz, and one for the final screen.  The quiz input just sets the final screen input version of itself.  But this feels clunky.  Is there a better way?

My goal would be to manage inputs in a single place, and just display them in multiple places in my site.  (Rather than have multiple copies of the inputs, and have to tie them together with function calls).

Comment: Since you can get the input by its "name" attribute, and since the name attribute doesn't have to be unique to one input, this is technically possible. But they are still two different inputs, so your logic needs a way to know which one is "correct" at any given time. You could make logic so that if one changes it updates all inputs with the same name to the value of the changed input.

Comment: Gotcha.  That's essentially what I'm currently doing, and what the answer below seems to suggest.  Sounds like there isn't really a way to abstract an input itself from it's "placement", so to speak.

Comment: No, but using "name" will reduce a lot of headache involving tracking id's or worrying about classes. And don't use onkeydown or any other keyboard specific event listener. You probably already know that.

Comment: Right now, I have a function that runs each time you click through a screen on the quiz.  It copies all of the values on that screen's inputs to the equivalent inputs on the final form.  It sounds like that's probably actually a fairly reasonable/recommended way to do this then.  I'm currently using unique ids, (one for a given quiz input, and one for it's matching final input).  Sounds like I could switch that to just use paired name attributes instead, which would certainly simplify things.  But the general idea sounds like it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared any code so hopefully this is what you need:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
    {
        document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML=document.getElementById("input1").value;
        document.getElementById("input2").value=document.getElementById("input1").value;
    }


</script>
```

Use `onkeydown="myFunction()"` inside input1.

Comment: So, this would imply that I would still need to have two separate inputs, and tie one to the other with a function.  That's what I am currently doing.  But I was wondering if there is some way to have a single input, but just show it multiple different places.  The goal is to not have to manage the input parameters and text on each copy of the input, and have to tie them together with function calls.  So when I can simply make changes to 1 input and have it show up in different places (rather than duplicate it as "input1" and "input2".)

Comment: Yes, the general idea of using name would be same. I am sorry i could not clarify things before i answered as i am not allowed to comment yet.